# Tag table not updating properly [Python 2.7, SQLite]

Tags: python, sqlite

My goal here is to run through a series of links who are sorted into category lists. These category lists may each contain a copy of a link, although links are associated with the same page and are unique.

There are approximately 240 categories, and I expect most links to be associated with at most 10 of those.

The script should process these links, using the actual URL as an identifier, and marking whether the URL appeared in a given category. It should, in the end, be trivial to get an output like this:

```
For a list = [item1, item2, ..., itemN],
item1 belongs to category1, category3,
item2 belongs to category 2, category5, category6,
etc.
```

Of course, that isn't the case. The script is currently successfully tagging each item the first time that it's discovered, and then ignoring it all other times. I've been trying to restructure the UPDATE line, to no avail. I have a suspicion that something's going wrong in my WHERE statement, but no amount of tinkering has proven successful so far.

The Python is attached below. For reference, the intended SQL commands are in a separate block also below.

```
Link is a two-part list containing 
    1. The URL, and 
    2. The Name of the page the URL is for.
CleanTag() is a function that removes spaces from the category list's 
    title for use as a column name in the table.
DatabaseName is, probably inappropriately, a table in my SQLite database.
Tag is currently the column name in the table, which takes an Integer.
Database is the connection object for my SQLite database.

for ProviderLink in ProviderLinks:
    URL = Link[0]
    Name = Link[1]
    Tag = CleanTag(Category)
    try:
        DBControl.execute('''INSERT OR ABORT INTO '''+DatabaseName+''' (providername, providerlink) 
                              VALUES (?, ?);''',
                                (Name, URL))

        LinkCount +=1

    except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
        pass

    DBControl.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO '''+TagDatabaseName+''' (providerlink) 
                              VALUES (?);''',
                              (URL,))
    DBControl.execute('''UPDATE '''+TagDatabaseName+'''
                         SET '''+'`'+Tag+'`'+''' = 1 
                         WHERE providerlink = '''+"'"+URL+"'"+''' ;
                                    ''') 

    Database.commit()
```

Below is the intended SQL commands, commented with my intention for each line:

```
INSERT OR ABORT INTO DatabaseName (providername, providerlink) VALUES (Name, URL);

    -- adds entry, returns an exception if entry with same URL already in table.
    -- using exception to track whether new entry was added.

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TagDatabaseName (providerlink) VALUES (URL);

    -- add entry to tag database if it isn't there; default value for all tags is 0

UPDATE TagDatabaseName SET Tag = 1 WHERE providerlink = URL;

    -- update entry with appropriate value for Tag.


COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ack. The code works fine, but my underlying assumption that the links were unique was a little weak. They're actually unique, even when the same entry appears in multiple category lists.

Moral of the story: check your assumptions!